# Login to Joomla admin page through a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, joomla2.5

i have developed an application in RoR 3.2.13 In one of my models user can create "projets" with a domain attribute. The projects are Joomla websites that user has already create. The domain attribute in the Ruby application is a URL to the Joomla administrator page. There is a password attribute too, in which user can enter joomla admin login's.

I would like to onertake joomla login authentication and access admin page with a click of the URL. Or to do the authentication in my RoR app or to enter the password through RoR database which is sqlite3. I know that Joomla uses Mysqli.
These are my thoughts.

Can anyone help?

Sorry for my English.
Thanks in advance.